# How can I fix the Poker Deck not to reinstantiate itself and restrict it to just the 52 cards in a deck?

Tags: java, class, methods, poker

I am building a a program to run 5 rounds of 5 card draw. I have bits of code I am still working on mainly my `PokerHandValue` class.

The only issues where the `PokerHandValue` class is evaluating both hands together instead of individually. The `PokerHandClass` which is where I think the issue sits is overly bloated due to me testing various components. How can I add in some code for the program to only evaluate one hand as one object?

My main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cards deck = new Cards();

    //setting loop for playing 5 hands
    int playedHands = 5;

    do {
        //creating the deck and player hands
        List<String> playableDeck = new ArrayList<>(deck.ShuffleDeck());
        List<String> playerHand = new ArrayList<>(playableDeck.subList(0, 5));
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            playableDeck.remove(i);
        }
        List<String> dealerHand = new ArrayList<>(playableDeck.subList(6, 11));
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            playableDeck.remove(j);
        }

        //assessing the value of hand dealt to player
        PokerHandValue playerValue = new PokerHandValue(playerHand);
        int pValue = playerValue.getValue();
        String pReason = playerValue.getResult();
        int playerHigh = playerValue.getHighCard();

        //assessing the value of hand dealt to player
        PokerHandValue dealerValue = new PokerHandValue(dealerHand);
        int dValue = dealerValue.getValue();
        String dReason = dealerValue.getResult();
        int dealerHigh = dealerValue.getHighCard();
        //displaying the output and value and results of each hands
        System.out.print("Black: " + playerHand.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
        System.out.println(" and White: " + dealerHand.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
        //determining the winner
        if (dValue < pValue) {
            System.out.println("White wins. - with a " + pReason + "\n");
        } else if (pValue < dValue) {
            System.out.println("Black wins. - with a " + dReason + "\n");
        } else if (playerHigh == dealerHigh) {
            if (playerHigh < dealerHigh) {
                String stringDHighCard = determineFace(Integer.toString(dealerHigh));
                System.out.println("Black wins. with a " + stringDHighCard + "\n");
            } else {
                String stringPHighCard = determineFace(Integer.toString(playerHigh));
                System.out.println("White wins. - with a " + stringPHighCard + "\n");
            }
        } else System.out.println("Tie.\n");
        playedHands--;
        //Removing the deck and hands to reshuffle deck and re-deal
        playableDeck.removeAll(playableDeck);
        playerHand.removeAll(playerHand);
        dealerHand.removeAll(dealerHand);
    }
    while (playedHands > 0);
}
static String determineFace(String faceValue){
    String face=faceValue;
    if (face.equals("11")) {
        face = "J";
    }
    else if(face.equals("12")) {
        face = "Q";
    }
    else if (face.equals("13")) {
        face = "K";
    }
    else face = "A";
    return face;
}
```

My `PokerHandValue` class to evaluate the individual poker hands:

```
import java.util.*;

class PokerHandValue {

    private int highCard;
    private int value;
    private String result;
    private List<String>thisHand;

    PokerHandValue(List<String> newHand) {

        this.thisHand=newHand;
        Collections.sort(thisHand);
        int i = 0;
        String card1 = thisHand.get(0);
        String card1num = Character.toString(card1.charAt(0));

        if (isJack(card1num)){
            card1num = "11";
        }
        if (isQueen(card1num)){
            card1num = "12";
        }
        if (isKing(card1num)){
            card1num = "13";
        }
        if (isAce(card1num)){
            card1num = "14";
        }
        int card1val = Integer.parseInt(card1num);
        String card1face = Character.toString(card1.charAt(1));

        String card2 = newHand.get(1);
        String card2num = Character.toString(card2.charAt(0));
        if (isJack(card2num)){
            card2num = "11";
        }
        if (isQueen(card2num)){
            card2num = "12";
        }
        if (isKing(card2num)){
            card2num = "13";
        }
        if (isAce(card2num)){
            card2num = "14";
        }
        int card2val = Integer.parseInt(card2num);
        String card2face = Character.toString(card2.charAt(1));

        String card3 = newHand.get(2);
        String card3num = Character.toString(card3.charAt(0));
        if (isJack(card3num)){
            card3num = "11";
        }
        if (isQueen(card3num)){
            card3num = "12";
        }
        if (isKing(card3num)){
            card3num = "13";
        }
        if (isAce(card3num)){
            card3num = "14";
        }
        int card3val = Integer.parseInt(card3num);
        String card3face = Character.toString(card3.charAt(1));

        String card4 = newHand.get(3);
        String card4num = Character.toString(card4.charAt(0));
        if (isJack(card4num)){
            card4num = "11";
        }
        if (isQueen(card4num)){
            card4num = "12";
        }
        if (isKing(card4num)){
            card4num = "13";
        }
        if (isAce(card4num)){
            card4num = "14";
        }
        int card4val = Integer.parseInt(card4num);
        String card4face = Character.toString(card4.charAt(1));

        String card5 = newHand.get(4);
        String card5num = Character.toString(card5.charAt(0));
        if (isJack(card5num)){
            card5num = "11";
        }
        if (isQueen(card5num)){
            card5num = "12";
        }
        if (isKing(card5num)){
            card5num = "13";
        }
        if (isAce(card5num)){
            card5num = "14";
        }
        int card5val = Integer.parseInt(card5num);
        String card5face = Character.toString(card5.charAt(1));

        String[] sortedHand = {card1, card2, card3, card4, card5};
        if ((card1face.equals(card2face) && card1face.equals(card3face) && card1face.equals(card4face)
                && card1face.equals(card5face)) && (card1.equals(sortedHand[i]) && card2num.equals(sortedHand[i + 1])
                && card3num.equals(sortedHand[i + 2]) && card4num.equals(sortedHand[i + 3]) &&
                card4num.equals(sortedHand[i + 4]))) {
            this.value = 9;
            this.result = "Straight Flush";
        } else if (((card1.charAt(1)==(card2.charAt(1)))&&(card1.charAt(1)==(card3.charAt(1)))&&
        (card1.charAt(1)==(card4.charAt(1))))||(((card2.charAt(1)==(card3.charAt(1)))&&(card2.charAt(1)==(card4.charAt(1)))&&
                (card2.charAt(1)==(card5.charAt(1)))&&(card1.charAt(1)==(card5.charAt(1)))))){
            this.value = 8;
            this.result = "Four of a kind";
        } else if (((card1.charAt(1)==(card2.charAt(1)))&&(card1.charAt(1)==(card3.charAt(1)))&&
                ((card4.charAt(1)==(card5.charAt(1)))))||((card1.charAt(1)==(card2.charAt(1)))
                &&(card3.charAt(1)==(card4.charAt(1)))&&((card3.charAt(1)==(card5.charAt(1)))))){
            this.value = 7;
            this.result = "Full House";
        } else if (card1face.equals(card2face) && card1face.equals(card3face) &&
                card1face.equals(card4face) && card1face.equals(card5face)) {
            this.value = 6;
            this.result = "Flush";
        } else if (card1.equals(sortedHand[i]) && card2num.equals(sortedHand[i + 1]) &&
                card3num.equals(sortedHand[i + 2]) && card4num.equals(sortedHand[i + 3])
                && card4num.equals(sortedHand[i + 4])) {
            this.value = 5;
            this.result = "Straight";
        } else if (((card1.charAt(1)==(card2.charAt(1)))&&(card1.charAt(1)==(card3.charAt(1))))||(
                card3.charAt(0)==card4.charAt(0)&&card3.charAt(0)==card5.charAt(0))
                ) {
            this.value = 4;
            this.result = "Three of a kind";
        } else if (((card1val == card2val || card1val == card3val || card1val == card4val || card1val == card5val) ||
                (card2val == card3val || card2val == card4val || card2val == card5val) || (card3val == card4val ||
                card3val == card5val) || (card4val == card5val)) && ((card1val == card2val || card1val == card3val ||
                card1val == card4val || card1val == card5val) || (card2val == card3val || card2val == card4val ||
                card2val == card5val) || (card3val == card4val || card3val == card5val) || (card4val == card5val))) {
            this.value = 3;
            this.result = "Two pair";
        } else if ((card1val == card2val || card1val == card3val || card1val == card4val || card1val == card5val)
                || (card2val == card3val || card2val == card4val || card2val == card5val) ||
                (card3val == card4val || card3val == card5val) || (card4val == card5val)) {
            this.value = 2;
            this.result = "Pair";
        } else {
            this.highCard=card1val;
            if (card1val < card2val || card1val < card3val || card1val < card4val) {
                this.highCard = card2val;
                if (card2val < card3val || card2val < card4val || card2val < card5val) {
                    this.highCard = card3val;
                    if (card3val < card4val || card3val < card5val) {
                        this.highCard = card4val;
                        if (card4val < card5val) {
                            this.highCard = card5val;
                        }
                    }
                }
                this.value = 1;
                this.result = "High Card of " + highCard;
            }
        }
    }
    int getValue(){
        return value;
    }

    String getResult(){
        return result;
    }

    int getHighCard() {
        return highCard;
    }

     private boolean isJack(String card) {
        if (card.equals("J")){
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
     private boolean isQueen(String card) {
        if (card.equals("Q")){
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
     private boolean isKing(String card) {
        if (card.equals("K")){
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
     private boolean isAce(String card) {
        if (card.equals("A")){
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }}

My Cards class.

    //Creating the cards and suits arrays
    private int card,suit;
    private static String[] CARDS = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};
    private static String[] SUITS = {"♠", "♣", "♦", "♥"};
    private List<String> inOrderDeck=new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> shuffledDeck;

    List <String> ShuffleDeck(){
        //creating a deck that is in order of C2-CA,D2-DA,H2-HA,S2-SA
        int n=52;
        int cnt=0;
        String[] deck = new String[n];
        for (String CARD : CARDS) {
            for (String SUIT : SUITS) {
                deck[cnt] = (CARD + SUIT);
                cnt++;
            }
        }
        //Adding set Arrays to List
        inOrderDeck.addAll(Arrays.asList(deck).subList(0, n));
        //Shuffling the deck
        List<String> shuffledDeck=new ArrayList<>(inOrderDeck);
        inOrderDeck.removeAll(inOrderDeck);
        Collections.shuffle(shuffledDeck);
        return shuffledDeck;
    }
}
```

Comment: My first observation is that the `ShuffleDeck` method has two responsibilities, it creates a `Deck` and then shuffles it.  Every time you call `ShuffleDeck` you will be adding 52 cards to the `inOrderDeck`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call `ShuffleDeck` you add 52 cards to `inOrderDeck`.  This is fine on the first hand, but for each subsequent hand the number of cards will increase by 52 which will result in about 270 cards in the deck by the start of the last hand.

You have three choices as I see it:

1. Clear the unshuffled deck before you return the shuffled deck in
   `ShuffledDeck`.
2. Dont use a static list to store your unshuffled
   deck and create it fresh  each time you call `ShuffleDeck`
3. Separate
   the creation of the unshuffled deck into a `createDeck` method, and
   do only the shuffling of the deck in the `ShuffleDeck` method.

I would go for the last one.

Comment: Gavin, thank you! This was a huge fix for me being able to bring in more to make this more complete!